# django updateview pass request.id to field

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a `UpdateView` class and I want to pass the user.id in `event_agency` of `fields` i.e the value of `event_agency` will be set to `user.id` and I will not have to take it as an input.

```
# view for the event update page
class EventUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Event

    # the fields mentioned beindexlow become the entyr rows in the update form
    fields = ['event_name', 'event_venue', 'event_type', 'event_agency']
```

Without using `UpdateView` it can be done by creating a form instance and passing `request`, but how to do it with `UpdateView` class?

I cannot for instance do

> `class EventUpdate(UpdateView, request):`

Answer (score 1):

Usually in that case, you do *not* add a field to that form. You can "patch" the instance in the form in the [**`form_valid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid), like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class EventUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Event
    # no event_agency
    fields = ['event_name', 'event_venue', 'event_type']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.event_agency = self.request.user.pk
        super().form_valid(form)
```

That being said, it looks like `event_agency` should be a `ForeignKey` to your user model, in that case, you should set this like `from.instance.event_agency = self.request.user`.

You can add the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) to prevent user from accessing your view if these are not authenticated.

Comment: do you mean `form.instance.event_agency = self.request.user` or `from.`

Comment: @afsara_ben: `form.instance.event_agency = self.request.user`. The `form` is passed as a parameter here.

Comment: i get this error `Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: ritu9>>": "Event.event_agency" must be a "Agency" instance.`

Comment: what i want is to assign `ritu9` to `event_agency` where i am logged in with `username` `ritu9`

Comment: @afsara_ben: that's not the id, that's the `request.user.username`. But as the error says, it does not look for a `User`, it looks for an `Agency` object, so something is wrong with the logic here.

Comment: which one is the `Agency` object here? This is the field in models. `event_agency = models.ForeignKey('agency.Agency', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank=True, null=True)`. and `event_agency` is a field in `agency.models`

Comment: @afsara_ben: well then it thus expects, like the error says, an `Agency` object, a `User`, or its username is *not* an `Agency` object. So you can not just "inject" such values in that field. Something seems to be broken with your modeling.